# Unable to start server in Eclipse Gallileo IDE with WAS7

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, appserver

Server not starting in Eclipse Gallileo IDE with WAS7.
I run the server from outside of Eclipse but I want to start it from within the eclipse 
Below are the details of my Workspace configurations :
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
WAS 7.0

An alert is coming saying "Cannot connect to VM socket closed".
I got the following exception in console :

```
JVMSHRC154E Escape character g not valid for cache name
<JIT: FullSpeedDebug: ignoring countString>
<JIT: FullSpeedDebug: ignoring countString>
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9shr24(13): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [JVMSHRC154E](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.java.messages/diag/appendixes/messages/shrc/message_jvmshrc154.html), it appears that somehow `-Xshareclasses:name=...%g...` is being added to your server JVM command line.  I do not know why there would be a difference between Eclipse and the command-line (perhaps a product issue that should be reported to IBM), but you could try working around the issue by adding `-Xshareclasses:nonfatal` to your server's generic JVM arguments.

Answer (score 0):

IBM has released development tools for `WebSphere Application Server (WAS)`.
You can download it from eclipse market place.
There are tools for the WAS7 and up. [(IBM Information page)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/tools/)

You probably need `WAS 7 Tools` - [marketplace page](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v70-developer-tools).

The short instruction is:
 In the eclipse click *Help->Eclipse Market Place->Search* `WebSphere Application Server Tools`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside eclipse installation folder go to \plugins.....\cdcla\eclipse\launch\simple.
2. Open the file websphere70.properties.
3. You will see the following content and remove the

> "_%g"

part and save it

```
shareclasses=webspherev70_%g,groupAccess,nonfatal
```